# Query with Hyphen (-) at the beginning always returns all documents of the index

Tags: elasticsearch

Here's the problem:
I have an index (ivy_task) with mapping and its field (barCode) like this

```
PUT ivy_task/_mapping/ElasticTaskInfo
{
 "properties" : {
    "barCode" : {
    "type" : "text",
    "fielddata" : true,
    "analyzer": "keyword"
    }
 }
}
```

Please note that i have 7 documents in this index

And when i use the query like this to search (with the hyphen at the beginning):

```
    POST /ivy_task/ElasticTaskInfo/_search/
    {
         "query":{"query_string": {
         "default_field": "barCode",
         "query": "-t"
         }},
         "size": 99
    }
```

As long as i put hyphen at the beginning of the query, It always returns all 7 documents. (For example: **-t, -d, -bbbbbbbbbbbbb. -aaaa1111**)
Can someone help me to explain why it returns all 7 documents ?
Here are the barCode of all 7 documents:

almostThere009

a-tinhte001

almostThere0011

almostThere0012

a-almostThere0014

almostThere0010

a-almostThere0013

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in a query string query, the minus sign `-` is a reserved character that stands for a [boolean operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators) whose goal is to not include the term next to it.

So all you queries are basically saying this:

- `-t`: "give me all documents that don't contain the term `t`
- `-d`: "give me all documents that don't contain the term `d`
- `-bbbbbbbbbbbbb`: "give me all documents that don't contain the term `bbbbbbbbbbbbb`
- `-aaaa1111`: "give me all documents that don't contain the term `aaaa1111`

On all the above cases, all documents are retrieved because they match the query.

Comment: Thank you, Val. Your answer helped me a lot.